# How to initialize DataTable with empty rows of certain length?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I know how many rows and columns I want in my `DataTable`. Let it be `rows X columns`. How can I initilize database so there will be already enough space.

I want to do this for convienience. I want to be able to write:  `datasource.Rows[i].ItemArray[j] = "2";` where `i` and `j` are less then `rows` and `columns` and don't cause an exception.

```
var datasource = new System.Data.DataTable();
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter Entity Framework, LocalDb, but I don't have too big problem to fetch data from there altough putting it into sheet is tricky because of relationships between tables, I am performing export of Survey results to EXCEL for IBM SPSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create a `DataTable` with x rows and y columns which is empty:

```
var datasource = new System.Data.DataTable();
int columns = 10;
int rows = 100;
for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
    datasource.Columns.Add();
string[] fields = new string[columns];
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    datasource.Rows.Add(fields);
```

Now this works for example:

```
datasource.Rows[25][6] = "2";
```

Note that it doesn't work via `DataRow.ItemArray` which you've shown in your question:

```
datasource.Rows[i].ItemArray[j] = "2"
```

because the `ItemArray` property-getter returns a new `object[]`, so it can be used only if you want to replace all fields in a row, therefore i've used the row-indexer: `Rows[25][6]`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you, especially for that note in the end of the post. : )

Comment: A bit related , but is there any way to initialize column with null value ? ( except doing it in a loop) . it seems that DataColumn's type can't be Nullable....

Comment: @RoyiNamir: ask a question and i'll try to answer. It's difficult to give answers in comments.